# Irreducible module of finite simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group and $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$.
Let $V$ be a nontrivial irreducible $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ module.
I would like to understand the relation of $|V|$ and $|G|_p$ (the $p$-part of $|G|$).
By checking the Atlas of Finite Groups, $|V|$ sometimes lesser than $|G|_p$ and sometimes larger than $|G|_p$.
For example, if $|G|_p=p$ and $V$ is any nontrivial irreducible $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$-module, then $|V|>|G|_p$, if $G=\mathrm{SL}_4(2)$ and $V$ is a nontrivial irreducible $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$-module of dimension 4, then $|V|<|G|_2$.

**Are there some inequalities to show the relation of $|V|$ and $|G|_p$?

For instance, could $|G|_p$ be bounded by a function of $|V|$?
when $|V|$ divides $|G|$?**

Any explanation, references suggestion and examples are appreciated.

Comment: Well $G \le {\rm GL}(V)$, so if $|V|=p^n$, then $|G|_p \le p^{n(n-1)/2}$, and the bound is sharp when $p=2$ and $G = {\rm GL}(V)$.

Comment: There's a related question of Richard Brauer, which asks whether the $p$-part of the dimension of an irreducible module in characteristic $p$ is at most the $p$-part of the group order. Thackray found a counterexample for the McLaughlin group, where there is a $2$-modular irreducible of dimension $7.2^9$, whereas the group order is only divisible by $2^7$. I later found an example for the symmetric group $S_{15}$, of dimension exactly $2^{12}$, whereas the group order is only divisible by $2^{11}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @DerekHolt.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @DaveBenson. What do you mean by "2-modular irreducible of dimension"? Is that mean that the dimension of an irreducible $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$ module?

Comment: In general, the phrase "$2$-modular irreducible" means an irreducible $kG$-module where $k$ is a field of characteristic two. In the cases of $McL$ and $S_{15}$, the modules I described can actually be written over the ground field ${\mathbb F}_2$, so they can be regarded as ${\mathbb F}_2 G$-modules.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your explanation. I have also found your paper.  @Dave Benson                                                                                                          "Benson, David. Some remarks on the decomposition numbers for the symmetric groups. Proc. Symp. Pure Math. Vol. 47. 1987."